# Dimensions lost in list to array conversion seemingly only when using line.split()

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am reading in files with two loops iterating through the names (my code after the MWE below) and using line.split(). In my code this produces a list which give the correct value (number of columns) when I check the length, but when I convert it to an array it becomes 1D with a shape (1245,) where the first value is the correct number of rows but the second dimension is now missing.

When I created a minimal working example it ran just fine, maintaining the dimensions, so I must be doing something silly with the read in. In the conversion it does show it's converting it to an array of lists which I can't find a solution to when searching, and oddly doesn't come up in the MWE.

(I believe this is my first post on here so please excuse any bad form).

MWE (which oddly works fine):

```
import numpy as np

entry_list = [['12','34','56'],['78','910','1112']]

print(len(entry_list[0]))
print(entry_list)
print(type(entry_list))

entry_array = np.array(entry_list)
print(type(entry_array))
print ('size: ',entry_array.shape)
print ('first row:  ',entry_array[0])
print ('one in one down: ',entry_array[1,1])
```

My code (does not work fine) which is looping through file names and using split before the part that mimics the above.  Note that I checked that the output of the split is exactly the syntax of the list used in the MWE.

```
prefix1 = "/Some/Path/prefix_"


#for each file in prefix1 set
for wl in range(300,700,100):
    for pa in range(0,185,5):
        pa = format(pa,'03')
        afile = str(prefix1) + str(wl) + str(pa) + "_suffix.dat"
        print (afile)
        with open(afile) as Frank1:
                f1_list = [line.split() for line in Frank1]
                print(len(f1_list[0])) #shows correct length of row (#columns)
                print(f1_list) #shows whole giant data set
                f1_array = np.array(f1_list)
                print (f1_array) # will show an array of list** like: [list(['0.1','0.2','0.3', 0.4', '0.5'])...list(['0.6', '0.7', '0.8', '0.9', '0.0'])]  
                print ('size: ',f1_array.shape) # now (1256,) or something
                print ('first row:  ',f1_array[0]) # shows first item correctly like ['0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.5']
                print ('one in one down: ',f1_array[3,3]) #can't, of course
```

** I have tried searching for a solution to this as a hint but haven't come across this exact problem as far as I can tell

Most pertinent output from the above print statements print(f1_array) and print('size: ',f1_array.shape) if that's any help:

[list(['0.300000', '33333.332031', '-22', '-4', '0.428851E+03', '0.236303E+02', '0.351592E+02', '0.276694E+01', '-0.104056E+01', '-0.000000E+00', '-22.14159', '22.14159', '180.00000-180.00000', '83.62063', '83.62063'])
list(['0.300000', '33333.332031', '-22', '-3', '0.428851E+03', '0.236303E+02', '0.378484E+02', '0.361102E+01', '-0.100348E+01', '-0.000000E+00', '-22.29910', '22.29910', '180.00000', '0.00000', '80.68976', '80.68976'])
list(['0.300000', '33333.332031', '-22', '-2', '0.428851E+03', '0.236303E+02', '0.390155E+02', '0.403966E+01', '-0.740604E+00', '-0.000000E+00', '-22.41093', '22.41093', '180.00000', '0.00000', '79.05499', '79.05499'])
...
list(['0.300000', '33333.332031', '22', '2', '0.428851E+03', '0.403838E+02', '0.390155E+02', '0.403966E+01', '-0.740604E+00', '0.000000E+00', '-22.41093', '22.41093', '180.00000', '0.00000', '79.05499', '79.05499'])
list(['0.300000', '33333.332031', '22', '3', '0.428851E+03', '0.403838E+02', '0.378484E+02', '0.361102E+01', '-0.100348E+01', '0.000000E+00', '-22.29910', '22.29910', '180.00000', '0.00000', '80.68976', '80.68976'])
list(['0.300000', '33333.332031', '22', '4', '0.428851E+03', '0.403838E+02', '0.351592E+02', '0.276694E+01', '-0.104056E+01', '0.000000E+00', '-22.14159', '22.14159', '180.00000', '0.00000', '83.62063', '83.62063'])]
size:  (1597,)

Comment: Almost certainly, there is a row that is not the same length as the other rows. If your numpy version is anything relatively recent, you should be getting a warning printed to the standard output saying something like: `VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.`

Comment: And actually, looking at your example output, the first list has length 15, the other lists have length 16, so that would do it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes that was exactly the problem.  The files are actually fixed width and the space delimiter was being used occasionally by a negative sign making a few rows one item short.  Thank you for the help!